# why does Ruby's Rational class treat string arguments differently from numeric arguments?

Tags: ruby, aspect-ratio, rational-number

I'm using ruby's Rational library to convert the width & height of images to  aspect ratios.

I've noticed that string arguments are treated differently than numeric arguments.

```
>> Rational('1.91','1')
=> (191/100)
>> Rational(1.91,1)
=> (8601875288277647/4503599627370496)

>> RUBY_VERSION
=> "2.1.5"
>> RUBY_ENGINE
=> "ruby"
```

FYI 1.91:1 is an aspect ratio recommended by Facebook for images on their platform.

Values like 191 and 100 are much more convenient to store in my database than 8601875288277647 and 4503599627370496. But I'd like to understand where this different originates before deciding which approach to use.

[The Rational test suite](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/ca6b174078fa15f33655be704d9409fdbc4f9929/test/ruby/test_rational2.rb) doesn't seem to cover this exact case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This is only an educated guess, based on some knowledge on how to implement such a feat.

As Kent Dahl already said, Floats are not precise, they have a fixed precision, which means 1.91 is really 1.910000000000000000001 or something like that, which ruby "knows" should be displayed as 1.91.

"1.91" on the other hand is a string, basically an array of characters: '1', '.', '9', '1'.

This said, here is what you need to do, to build the rational out of floats:

1. Get rid of the . (mathematically by multiplying the numerator and denominator with 10^x, or multiplying with ten as many times, as there are numbers behind the .)
2. Find the greatest common denominator (gcd)
3. Divide num and denom with the gcd

Step 1 however, is a little different for Float and String:

- The Float, we will have to multiply with 10^x, where x is (because of the precision) not 2 (as one would think with 1.91), but more something like 16 (remember: 1.9100...1).
- For the String, we COULD cast it into a float and do the same trick, but hey, there is an easier way: We just count the number of characters behind the dot (which is 2), remove the dot and multiply the denom with 10^2... This is not only the easier, but also the more precise way.

The big numbers might disappear again, when applying step 3, that's why you will not always get those strange results when dealing with rationals from floats.

TLDR: The numbers will be built differently based on the arguments being String, or FLoat. FLoats can produce long-ass numbers, because precision.

Answer (score 1):

The Float 1.91 is stored as a double which has a given amount of precision, limited by binary presentation. The equivalent Rational object retains this precision a such as possible, so it is huge. There is no way of storing 1.91 exactly in a double, but the value you get is close enough for most uses.

As for the String, it represents a different value - the exact value of 1.91 - and as you create a Rational it retains it better. It is more correct than the Float,  UT takes longer to use for calculations.

This is similar to the problem with 1.0/3 as it "goes on forever" 0.333333...etc, but Rational can represent it exactly.